# Existe uma maneira de atribuir valores à variáveis simbólicas após derivá-las utilizando sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, matemática, ipython-notebook, sympy

Olá, preciso escrever um código que derive uma função informada pelo usuário e depois atribua valores às variáveis para realizar o cálculo. O problema é que é necessário que as variáveis sejam simbólicas para o sympy derivá-las e caso assumam algum valor numérico, o sympy não realiza a derivação. Aqui o que já tentei:

```
from sympy import diff, var

r, h = var('r h')

def derivadaVolume():
    volume = 3.14*(r**2)*h
    return diff(volume, h) 

h = 3    
r = 2
derivadaVolume()
```

O erro: *ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: 3*

Porém, se por exemplo, derivo em relação a r e atribuo valor apenas a h:

```
from sympy import diff, var

r, h = var('r h')

def derivadaVolume():
    volume = 3.14*(r**2)*h
    return diff(volume, r) 

h = 3    
derivadaVolume()
```

**Output:** *18.84*

Também já tentei atribuir a uma variável a derivada retornada na função derivadaVolume() mas ao alterar os valores de r e h, nada muda no valor da variável:

```
from sympy import diff, var

r, h = var('r h')

def derivadaVolume():
    volume = 3.14*(r**2)*h
    return diff(volume, r) 
    
derivada = derivadaVolume()
h = 3
r = 2
derivada
```

**Output:** *6.28ℎ*

Alguém sabe se é possível resolver esse problema? Existe alguma outra biblioteca que torne isso capaz?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from sympy import diff, var

r, h = var('r h')

def derivadaVolume():
    volume = 3.14*(r**2)*h
    return diff(volume, h) 

h = 3    
r = 2
derivadaVolume()
```

Quando faz isso, você está dizendo que `h` vale 3 antes de calcular a derivada e, quando esta é calculada, você estaria tentando derivar em relação a uma constante, 3. Isso não faz sentido e por isso dá erro.

Esse problema você solucionou na segunda tentativa, em que calculou a derivada antes de atribuir os valores:

```py
from sympy import diff, var

r, h = var('r h')

def derivadaVolume():
    volume = 3.14*(r**2)*h
    return diff(volume, r) 
    
derivada = derivadaVolume()
h = 3
r = 2
derivada
```

Mas derivou em relação a `r` (não entendi porque isso mudou).

A questão é que apenas atribuir o valor a uma variável não impactará diretamente no valor da variável, como imaginou. Você precisa substituir os valores na derivada:

```
resultado = derivada.subs({
  h: 3,
  r: 2
})
```

Assim, `resultado` será, como indicado, o valor de `derivada` com as variáveis `h` e `r` sendo substituídas por 3 e 2, respectivamente.